# Apple Files Application "Raname" file/folder functionality not work in file provider extention

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4, fileprovider-extension

[image]

[image]

[image]

While Rename any item in Apple Files application vi File Provider Extension not work it display bellow error

> The requested Operation couldn't be completed because the feature is
>   not supported.

In my `FileProviderItem` class i have set capabilities as bellow

```
    var capabilities: NSFileProviderItemCapabilities {
        return .allowsAll
    }
```

How i can rename document in apple file Application thru my file provider extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not implement this feature in my project. 
However I belive you should override the method

```
func renameItem(withIdentifier itemIdentifier: NSFileProviderItemIdentifier, 
         toName itemName: String, 
completionHandler: @escaping (NSFileProviderItem?, Error?) -> Void)
```

in your *NSFileProviderExtension*.

Please refer to:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileproviderextension/2882095-renameitem

-nls

Comment: can you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783317/apple-fileprovider-extention-in-file-application-remove-copy-duplicate-operatio